# response in view instead of HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, django-views

Is there a way to only get a response to the view instead of making a HttpResponse?

I'm making a xml request, and I want to use some data from teh response before doing a HttpRepsonse.

I'm new to Python and Django.

Comment: A custom middleware with [`process_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/) should help in this case.

Comment: you may send request to view and get response from view so kindly update your question what you want to do and some of your progress with code.